# Seeking humorous film, parodying modern architecture in a near-future setting

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm trying to find a short film, that I saw twice on American public television in the late 1980s or early 1990s.  It was used as a filler/bumper on a PBS station to fill up the remaining fifteen minutes after they broadcast a forty-five-minute British program.

It was about a day in the life of a hyper-modern architect in a near-future setting.  (I can't remember exactly what about the setting suggested that it took place ten or twenty years in the future, but that is my impression.  I think maybe the whole production just has a slightly futuristic look.)  The joke is that the architect produces buildings that are very difficult to use.  A rich couple has him design their house, because there so much cachet to his work, but they are upset when he places a huge downward-pointing spike in the middle of their living room.

The architect's working mantra (which he and other people in the film repeat) is, "A location is not just a location."  He and his admirers treat this as a deep statements, but other people just seem confused by it.

At the end of the day, the architect heads home, and the end of the film shows that, ironically, he lives in a classic Victorian house.

Comment: FWIW, this is only a mild exaggeration of some real-life architects.  Frank Lloyd Wright famously had a corridor to a bedroom that was a very tight squeeze, I believe less than half a metre wide.

Comment: "Frank Lloyd Wright famously had a corridor to a bedroom that was a very tight squeeze, I believe less than half a metre wide" ...My wife keeps saying she wants a corridor like that leading to our kitchen; to stop me fridge-raiding